# Angular 7 - My Application suddenly started complaining No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: angular, laravel, api

I have an application developed with Angular-7 as frontend and Laravel-5.8 as backend.  I set the CORS in Laravel. Initially, everything was working perfectly even when I cleared browser cache. But suddenly I found this error when I tried to Login:

> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I checked my backend and everything is intact. Then I inspected the frontend and found the CORS error in the console

[cors_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptecx.png)

Laravel backend

config/cors.php

```
return [

    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],    //['Content-Type', 'X-Requested-With'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],   // ex: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT',  'DELETE']
    'exposedHeaders' => [],     //['Authorization'],
    'maxAge' => 0,

];
```

kernel.php

```
    protected $middleware = [
     ...
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];
 array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
      ...
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
            \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        ],
    ];
```

authentication.service.ts

```
     import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
     import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
     import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
     import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
     import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

     @Injectable({
       providedIn: 'root'
     })
     export class AuthenticationService {

     isLoginSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.hasToken());

     constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

      /*
       Purpose: if we have token the user is loggedIn, return boolean
       if we have token the user is loggedIn
       ===============================================================
      */
       private hasToken(): boolean {

       if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
        const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
       if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
         return true;
       }  else {
         return false;
       }
      } else {
        return false;
      }
     }

     /*
      Purpose: update login status
      =============================
     */
      setLoginSubject(status: boolean) {
      this.isLoginSubject.next(status);
     }

     /*
      Purpose: @returns {Observable<T>}
      ===============================================================
     */
     isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
     return this.isLoginSubject.asObservable();
     }

     /*
     Purpose: login request
     ===================================
    */
     login(user: any) {
      return this.http.post<any>(environment.apiUrl + '/login', user)
        .pipe(map(response => {
          if (response.data && response.data.token) {
            response.data.spotTheBall = [];
            response.data.playToWin = 0;
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(response.data));
            this.isLoginSubject.next(true);
          }
          return response;
      }));
     }
    }
```

login.component.ts

```
     import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
     import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
     import { Router } from '@angular/router';
     import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
     import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
     import { AuthenticationService } from '../../../core/auth/services/authentication.service';
     import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
     import { from } from 'rxjs';
     import { Ng4LoadingSpinnerService } from 'ng4-loading-spinner';

     declare var $;

     @Component({
       selector: 'app-login',
       templateUrl: './login.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
     })
     export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild ('validateform') validateform: NgForm;
    config: any;
    loginModel: any = {};
     name: string;
    @Input() userInfo: any;
    @Input() userLoginStatus: boolean;

     constructor(
      private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
      private spinnerService: Ng4LoadingSpinnerService,
      private router: Router,
      private toastr: ToastrService,
     ) { }

    ngOnInit() {

      const loggedInSubscriber = this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn();
      loggedInSubscriber.subscribe(response => {
        this.userLoginStatus = response;
      });

      // check for the user data if logged in
      if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
        const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        this.userInfo = currentUser;
      }
       this.config = environment;
       this.name = 'Test name';
      }

     /*
      Purpose: handles user login
      ===================================
     */
     onLogin(loginform: any) {
     if (!loginform.valid) { // return false if form not valid
      return false;
     }
     this.spinnerService.show();
     this.loginModel.remember = 1;
     this.authenticationService.login(this.loginModel)
       .pipe(first())
       .subscribe(
        response => {
          if (!response['success']) {

            this.toastr.error(response['message']);
            return false;
          }
          this.userInfo = response['data'];
          this.toastr.success('Login Successful.');
          loginform.reset();
          loginform.resetForm();
          this.router.navigate(['home']);
        },
        error => {
          this.spinnerService.hide();
            this.toastr.error(error);
        }
      );
     }
     }
```

When I login, I expected to get to home page, which was happening before but suddenly it has the CORS error.

Comment: Try to add OPTIONS to your allowedMethods..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

> [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

plugin. I think that solve the problem.